# Q: How to grant analyze privileges to pghero user

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I've successfully setup pgHero using the permissions guide [here](https://github.com/ankane/pghero/blob/master/guides/Permissions.md).

Everything is working, including historical query stats, except for the ability run analyze on queries that it shows are slow.

I get `PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied for table <tableName>`

How can I grant permission to analyze to the pghero user?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is as simple as granting SELECT (and whatever other) privileges to the pghero user like so:

```
# Grant select access for all current tables
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO pghero;

# For all future tables
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE <main-user> IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO pghero;
```